# Parsing Through JSON Object From Retrofit Response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm pretty new to android dev and I first made a weather app that displays the horly forecast along with the current forecast. I wanted to add a button that allows the user to see the daily forecast but from the API call it looks like it returns a JSON object. I have been stuck on this for days and I have no idea what to do. [image]

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APICall apiCall = retrofit.create(APICall.class);
        Call<WeatherModel> call = apiCall.getHourAndAstroDetails(latlong, "7");
        System.out.println(call.request().url());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherModel> call, Response<WeatherModel> response) {
                if (days == 1) {
                    weatherList = response.body().getForecast().getForecastday().get(0).getHour();
                    System.out.println("this is the size of weatherList" + weatherList.size());
                    setAdapter(weatherList);
                } else if (days == 7) {
                    dailyForcast = response.body().getForecast().getForecastday().get(0).getDay();
                }


                String sunriseTime = response.body().getForecast().getForecastday().get(0).getAstro().getSunrise();
                String sunsetTime = response.body().getForecast().getForecastday().get(0).getAstro().getSunset();
                sunriseTextView.setText(sunriseTime);
                sunsetTextView.setText(sunsetTime);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherModel> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just to add since I think I left some info out. I need to get into the Day{} but i need to get a List so I can attach it to a recyclerView. I'm either coming at this the wrong way or something It's so frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a model class for all the data that you are getting from the api, so you can work with data more easily.

This article explains that,

https://medium.com/swlh/basic-usage-of-retrofit-in-kotlin-for-fetching-json-8b9d37999058

Comment: The solution was so simple. I used jsonschema2pojo and for some reason, I forgot I can create a custom class. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Glad it worked!